# bootstrap admin credentials do not exist in the config store

Tags: artifactory, high-availability

I am doing Aritfactory HA Installation and Setup. The primary server starts successfully, but the Secondary server always fails to start. The error is as follows:

```
    2017-12-28 08:31:17,209 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:231) - Artifactory context starting up 49 Spring Beans...
Thu Dec 28 08:31:17 UTC 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-12-28 08:31:17,443 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:99) - Application could not be initialized: bootstrap admin credentials do not exist in the config store
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:224) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$2(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:186) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:95) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.7.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: bootstrap admin credentials do not exist in the config store
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:241) ~[artifactory-core-5.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:124) ~[artifactory-core-5.7.1.jar:na]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: bootstrap admin credentials do not exist in the config store
        at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.lambda$14(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:343) ~[artifactory-core-5.7.1.jar:na]
```

Is there any suggestion about this error?

Thanks,
Jiang Chuan.

Comment: The problem is solved by using a new database. I think it is because there is some wrong configurations in the old database.

Comment: How can you use a new database without first migrating the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing owner and permission of db.properties will solve your issue.